# How to make a setTimeout call to same function from within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

```
 (function () {
        if (some scripts loaded) {
            otherFunction();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout( "CALL_SELF_AGAIN_HERE" , 100);
        }
    })();
```

How to  call anonymous function from within anonymous function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it an identifier:

```
(function named () {
    if (some scripts loaded) {
        otherFunction();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout( named , 100);
    }
})();
```

This is what's known as a "named function expression". The identifier is only in scope *inside* the function it refers to.

Don't use [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) since it's deprecated and will actually throw a syntax error in strict mode.

Comment: It's only "visible" inside that closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating any new top level function names, you can put your code in a local function that gives you a function name to both execute initially and to pass to `setTimeout()`:

```
(function () {
    function doit() {
        if (some scripts loaded) {
            otherFunction();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(doit, 100);
        }
    }
    // execute the first time
    doit();
})();
```

Comment: Accepted @James Allardice's answer as it was simpler, and respecting the scope as well.